# PageScroll scrolls below the title

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using animated scrolling functionality [ngx-page-scroll](https://github.com/Nolanus/ngx-page-scroll). When scrolling down the page, scrolling hides the `<h1>` tag. And as a result, only cards are displayed. How to make it so that when scrolling the page it stops at the heading, that is, at the `<h1>` tag?

menu html

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="center">
            <nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
                <a mat-button pageScroll href="#pizza">
                    <span>Pizza</span>
                </a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

section html

```
<h1 id="pizza">
        Pizza
</h1>
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column">
    <div fxFlex.gt-md="0 1 33.3" fxFlex.gt-xs="0 1 50" fxFlex="100" *ngFor="let picture of pictures">
        <mat-card class="card card-picture">
            <img mat-card-image [src]="picture.img">
            <mat-divider [inset]="true"></mat-divider>
            <mat-card-content style="padding-top: 10px;" fxFlex="1 1 auto">
                <p class="title">
                    {{picture.title}}
                </p>
                <p class="subtitle">
                    {{picture.subtitle}}
                </p>
            </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share something reproduceable?

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava I don't understand what you mean this is all I have that concerns `pageScroll`

Comment: Could you put your code somewhere where we can run it - so it includes any libraries it depends on for example? [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is worth looking at to help frame your question so we can more easily help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your header is covering up the heading maybe, if it's fixed at the top. There is a pageScrollOffset property you can add to change where it scrolls to relative to the heading.

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutAlign="center">
            <nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
                <a mat-button pageScroll [pageScrollOffset]="-50" href="#pizza">
                    <span>Pizza</span>
                </a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```